# How to capture a snapshot in MPC-HC without the black lines?

Tags: media-player-classic

How to capture a snapshot in MPC-HC without the black lines at the top and at the bottom?

Here is the example, attached.

The video has the black lines at the top and at the bottom.

[image]

I want to capture a snapshot of only the video itself, without the black spaces (lines).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: How have you been capturing the screenshot so far? Are you trying to use a function built in to MPC, or an OS-level screenshot function, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black lines are due to the video not being in the same [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) as the display. You can do a few things:

- Don't show the video full-screen when snapping the screenshot. Manipulate the proportions of MPC-HC to match the video.
- Select videos that match the display aspect ratio.
- Crop the image, as below. There are free tools, such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/), which was used to improve that screenshot.

[image: Clipboard Image]